# How to use vi to quickly jump to a previously browsed line

Tags: vimrc

For example, I'm browsing the 700th line, and I typed ":456" to jump to the 456th line. Now I want to quickly return to the 700th line. Is there any shortcut key instead of typing ":700".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jumplist (see :help jumplist) can be navigated with `Ctrl-o`, to go back to
line 700 (and `Ctrl-i` would take you back to line 456 again).

If you want to be able to do this with relative jumps (i.e. after typing `7j`
to go seven lines down, use `Ctrl-o` to return to where you before the relative
jump), you can use following two remaps in your .vimrc:

```
" store relative line number jumps in the jumplist.
nnoremap <expr> k (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'k'
nnoremap <expr> j (v:count > 1 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'j'
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems remiss<sup>1</sup> to not mention what some would consider the fastest way to jump back to the previous line: `''`, i.e. just double-tap apostrophe. The nice thing is that you can bounce back and forth between two lines with the same command.

A couple things to be aware of:

- This takes you to *the first non-blank character* of the previous line (as all jump-to-mark commands starting with `'` do). To return to the same line *and* column double-tap back-tick (`` ` ``) instead.
- Like `ctrl-o` this only works after motions that are registered in the jumplist.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Just to be clear I mean remiss on the part of the community and *not* @mattb specifically!</sub>